# django mongodb connections by using djongo and pymongo

Tags: python, django, mongodb, pymongo, djongo

Can I use djongo to connect with Mongodb database and for complex queries i want to use Pymongo in my django project. please let me now if it is possible.

As I wanted to do fulltext search in my project which is possible by pymongo.

'''
details = collection_name.find({"$text": {"$search": "python"}},{"score": {"$meta": "textScore"}}).sort([("score",{"$meta":"textScore"})])
'''

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it's possible. In my project I do it using `mongoengine` as below code in `settings.py`

```
from mongoengine import connect
MONGO_DATABASE_NAME = '<database_name>'
MONGO_HOST = 'mongodb://<host_name>'
MONGO_PORT = <port_no.>
connect(MONGO_DATABASE_NAME, host=MONGO_HOST, port=MONGO_PORT)
```

However, [this](https://www.mongodb.com/compatibility/mongodb-and-django) is the best place I found out which has multiple ways of using MongoDB with Django